# Access completion proposals from open xtext Editor programmatically

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

Access xtext/xbase-ContentAssist programmatically

Hello. I am trying to access the CompletionProposal of my generated xtext-editor programmatically from within another plugin(View). The Editor is open and i have MyEditor/XbaseDocumentProvider/XtextDocument. Does someone has hint for me?

Comment: i am not aware of such a possibility. maybe you could explain your actual usecase.
also when this should "happen". maybe you can "intercept" or customize org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.contentassist.ConfigurableCompletionProposal.apply(IDocument) or other apply methods and callback some listeners there

Comment: Field field = AbstractTextEditor.class.getDeclaredField("fSourceViewer");
   field.setAccessible(true);
   viewer = (XtextSourceViewer) field.get(editor);
   contentAssistant = viewer.getContentAssistant();
   computeCompletionProposalsMethod = ContentAssistant.class.getDeclaredMethod("computeCompletionProposals", ITextViewer.class, int.class);
   computeCompletionProposalsMethod.setAccessible(true);
   
   
   Object[] obj = (Object[]) computeCompletionProposalsMethod.invoke(contentAssistant, viewer, offset);

Comment: but what is your usecase. do you want tot reuse all proposals in your view?